# Angular reuse component in another position in dom WITHOUT reinitialization

Tags: angular

In our Angular (v11) application, we use some components multiple times in different places in DOM, and they are toggled in/out with ngIf's. Mostly because of reponsive design decisions. Example:

```
<comp1 ngIf*="mobile">
```

... and in another position, probably within some other components:

```
<comp1 ngIf*="desktop">
```

When we switch our view, the default Angular behaviour in this case is, the tag is removed from dom from the position1, the component will be killed, the tag is added in other position2 in dom, and the component will be reinitialized again.

Can we somehow without any component change, reuse this component in another position in DOM?

Comment: css grid can be very useful for your case https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to trigger the component life cycle, what about using `ngClass` and define your positioning rules with css? Something like

```
<div [ngClass]="isMobile ? 'mobile' : 'desktop'"></div>
```

and with your css:

```
.mobile {
   top: 1px;
}

.desktop {
   top: 100px;
}
```

This way only the appearance is updated and the component state is retained.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ngSwitchCase the Dom will automatically re render, for good measure. or use ngClass and bind the element to different locations using simple Boolean logic there are other more complex ways to do this but if its only a few locations it just makes more sense for code maintenance concerns to do it simple. using switchcase just allows one to re render the Dom based upon condition.  you can also use ngOnInit, ngOnDestory with directives to generate components which is what we do - but thats a lot of code to maintain if you don't have too.

**yourloading.component.html**

```
<ng-container >
<div [ngSwitch]="deviceType">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'desktop'"> <app-component1 [layout]="desktop"></app-component1></div></ng-container>
</div>
<div *ngSwitchCase="'mobile'"> <app-component1 [layout]="mobile"></app-component1></div></ng-container>
</div>
</div>
</ng-container>
```

**yourloading.component.ts**
after your opening component decorator

```
deviceType ?: string;
```

**component1.component.ts**

```
//import Input
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Input() layOut ?: string;

topLocation: boolean;
bottomLocation: boolean;
ngOnInit(){
if(layout === 'desktop'){
   topLocation = true;
}
if(layout === 'mobile'){
   bottomLocation = true;
}

}
```

**component1.component.css**

```
.top{
margin-top: 0;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
}
.bottom {
margin-bottom: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
}
.show{
visibility: visible;
height: 100%;
}
.hide{
visibility: none;
height: 0;
}
```

**component1.component.html**

```
<div [ngClass]="topLocation ? 'show':'hide'">
  component html cool things maybe call another component with designs or something or change other css classes
</div>
<div [ngClass]="bottomLocation ? 'show':'hide'">
  component html cool things
</div>
```